# How to get element with plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the li element.How to do?tks? I am a newbie

```
 html = "<ul id=\"leftMenu\"><li id=\"a.aspx\"></li></ul>";
//alert(html.children[0]);
```

$(html).find("li:eq(0)") //I dot not want to with jquery

Comment: Here, great place to start learning JS http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var html = "<ul id=\"leftMenu\"><li id=\"a.aspx\"></li></ul>";
div.innerHTML = html;
alert(div.children[0].children[0]);
```